# Float integer division and setting variable value

Tags: bash, script

I am currently learning the world of bash scripting. I am aware that bash by itself does not do arithmetic with floating integers. I have done some research and have found that there are tools that can help get the job done. I decided to use the `bc` calculator tool. The only issue is the syntax. I am able to get results but not in the desired way. How can I assign `$N_RESULTS` the value of the math operation?

```
//I get arithmetic error with this syntax
DECI=128.17333
let "N_RESULTS = ($DECI - 1) / 10 + 1" | bc -l
echo $N_RESULTS
```

_

```
//I get correct results if do something like this
DECI=128.17333
echo "($DECI - 1) / 10 + 1" | bc -l
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
N_RESULTS=$( echo "($DECI - 1) / 10 + 1" | bc -l )
```

#### What `let` does

Consider:

```
let "N_RESULTS = ($DECI - 1) / 10 + 1" | bc -l
```

This pipeline has two parts.  The first is the shell's `let` command.  Because of the `|` symbol, output from the `let` command is passed to stdin of the `bc` command.  While '`let` is capable of performing integer arithmetic and can assign values to variable, it does not produce any output.  Hence, even if it ran correctly, it would pass nothing to `bc`.

Here is an example of a working `let` command:

```
$ let "result = (123 - 1) / 10 + 1"
$ echo $result
13
```

If, however, we were to supply a floating point argument, an error would result:

```
$ let "result = (123.0 - 1) / 10 + 1"
bash: let: result = (123.0 - 1) / 10 + 1: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0 - 1) / 10 + 1")
```

The `let` command, like the rest of the shell, only does integer arithmetic.

#### What `bc` does

`bc` does floating point arithmetic and can be used to assign and manipulate variables:

```
$ echo "result = (123.0123 - 1) / 10 + 1; print result" | bc -l
13.20123000000000000000
```

Note, however, that the above does not, by itself create any shell-usable variables.  The definition of `result` expires when the `bc` finishes processing.  In order to pass the value back to the shell, we need to do a shell variable assignment such as:

```
$ result=$(echo "(123.0123 - 1) / 10 + 1" | bc -l )
$ echo $result
13.20123000000000000000
```

The `$(...)` construct is called command substitution.  It runs a command, in this case the echo and bc pipeline, and puts its stdout on the command line where it is assigned to the variable `result`.

As a side note, it usually considered best practices to use lower-case names for your shell variables.  The system's shell variables are all upper-case and you don't want to accidentally overwrite one of them.

#### What is the `bc` equivalent for `[[ $offset -lt $result ]]`

The shell `test` commands, including `[` and `[[`, produce a useful exit code that can be used in `if`, `while`, and other contexts, such as `&&` and `||`, where exit codes are used to determine program flow.  `bc` does not emulate that behavior.  It returns an exit code of `0` for any successful calculation. It returns non-zero exit codes if an error occurred.  The examples below show how, with the help of `grep`, `bc` can be used to set useful exit codes.

In GNU `bc`, relational expressions evaluate to `1` for true and `0` for false.  So, to test whether `offset` is less than `result`, we just check whether `bc` returns `0` or `1`.  Here, `grep` is used to examine the output from `bc` and set an appropriate return code that can be used in `if`, `while`, or other places where the shell would test for a return code.  For example:

```
$ offset=1.25; result=1.33
$ echo "$offset < $result" | bc -l | grep -q 1 && echo yes || echo no
yes
$ offset=1.35
$ echo "$offset < $result" | bc -l | grep -q 1 && echo yes || echo no
no
```

Under non-GNU `bc`, the same thing can be done but a formal `if` statement is required:

```
echo "if ($offset < $result) print 1 else print 0 " | bc -l | grep -q 1 && echo yes || echo no
```

Comment: +1 This is a great explanation. One more thing. How would I be able to do comparison with a floating point number `while [[ $OFFSET -lt $result ]] ; do` ?

Comment: @Code_Ed_Student See updated answer.

Comment: I have another question based on similar topic: http://superuser.com/questions/821023/creating-directory-name-from-file-name-strip-out-non-alpha-numeric-characters